# X86 Assembly - How to calculate instruction opcodes length in bytes

Tags: c#, assembly, x86, machine-code

I'm trying to learn X86 Assembly (for learn reverse engineering). 
I learned C# and C\C++ language and pretty of IL

Probably my main problem is English language because i'm Persian, and also i can't find any helpful document to learn X86 assembly that written in Persian. so what i decided to do what i did for learn C# and C++.
I tried reading X86 samples and hello worlds but i failed because i can't understand which Register i have to choose for instructions and other problems that can't be solved by only look at source codes.

So i decided to change my strategy and do a challenge : **Write a X86 Disassembler**
I'm mad, i know. But we can't say it's impossible. 
The first think that i need to understand (but no memorize) is this tables : http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html

I'm good with opcodes but i can't understand how to calculate size of operands or what about registers hex bytes ?

Sorry for my bad English.

PS. I want doing it using C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the size of each asm instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1399861/995714), [instruction lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4567903/995714), [Determind length of instructions in bytes](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/12434/2563)